# Cannot find resources on instrumented jar by cobertura

Tags: java, integration-testing, cobertura

I have an application that tries to load a resource on a given Jar, by the following way:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Resources/someresource.xml");
```

When working with an instrumented version of the Jar by Cobertura, null is returned.

When Working with the the un-instrumented version of the same Jar, the resource stream returned as requested.

Can someone help?

Comment: What does the jar look like exploded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't find the cause of this, but ignoring the resource file on instrumentation did help. Actually, because I'm working with Jetty - I copied "Resources/someresource.xml" under the /class directory of the WEB-INF and it worked.